# Can't log in after AD Username Change

Tags: macos, user-account, login, active-directory

We currently are updating all our Active Directory usernames from the old format (FirstnameLastinitial) to a new format (FirstnameLastname). So far, the Windows side of these changes have been working great, no issues with the change. When it comes to changing the OSX machines, things start to break.

On AD, we changed the username, both the "User logon name" and the "User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)", to the new format. This breaks the on-network logon on our Macs, and that user cannot log in at all, with both the old and new username. If i change the username back, after replication is done I can log back in.

So far my searching has only turned up mainly issues with AD passwords, not the username. I did find the ADacctChange script from https://clburlison.com/ADacctChange/ however the script would not work on my test Mac (both 10.10.5 and 10.11.4).

Comment: If I remember correctly, when i did this with Server 2008, you had to disconnect from AD, change the username on the Mac then rejoin AD.  Changing the username on the Mac involved creating a new user account and migrating all the data from one account to the next.

Comment: Thanks for the help, worked out for my account. I only had to change the account name and home directories for the already existing accounts.

Comment: Good to hear.   Apple must have changed something for the better; when we tried just renaming the account and directory, it didn't work.